# Как удалить из столбца строку с пустым списком?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Дан датафрейм:

```
d = {'name': [['rick', 'mike', 'morty'], [], ['brick', 'nick'], ['rick', 'reaven', 'bart', 'homer'], ['rick', 'morty']],
     'Date': ['11/05/2011', '9/02/2010', '1/01/2014', '12/20/2020', '9/30/2009'],
     'Address': ['AR', 'YU', 'RU', 'EU', 'BY']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Как удалить строку с пустым списком?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вот так еще тоже работает:

```
df.loc[df.name.astype(bool)]
'''
                          name        Date Address
0          [rick, mike, morty]  11/05/2011      AR
2                [brick, nick]   1/01/2014      RU
3  [rick, reaven, bart, homer]  12/20/2020      EU
4                [rick, morty]   9/30/2009      BY
```

Comment: Кстати да, это ещё короче я что-то такое думал, но не сообразил из обычного питона в пандас перенести )

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.str.len()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
res = df.loc[df["name"].str.len().gt(0)]
```

результат:

```
In [104]: res
Out[104]:
                          name        Date Address
0          [rick, mike, morty]  11/05/2011      AR
2                [brick, nick]   1/01/2014      RU
3  [rick, reaven, bart, homer]  12/20/2020      EU
4                [rick, morty]   9/30/2009      BY
```

Comment: Вообще `.str.len()` применительно к спискам как-то контринтуитивно в пандасе работает )

Comment: @CrazyElf, хммм, а в чем именно?

Comment: Ну str же по идее как со строкой должен обращаться, не? )

Answer (score 4):

Можно через `apply` применить `len` и потом проверить, что длина списка не нулевая:

```
df = df[df['name'].apply(len) > 0]
```

`df` после этого:

```
    name                        Date        Address
0   [rick, mike, morty]         11/05/2011  AR
2   [brick, nick]                1/01/2014  RU
3   [rick, reaven, bart, homer] 12/20/2020  EU
4   [rick, morty]                9/30/2009  BY
```

Comment: можно ещё так попробовать  `df[df['name'].apply(bool)]`

Comment: @Danis Уже есть такой ответ и он реально хороший )

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно удалить сам список, то можно с помощью цикла for таким образом:

```
for i in d['name']:
    if len(i) == 0:
        del d['name'][d['name'].index(i)]
```

Обратите внимание, что если пустых списков будет больше одного, то это не сработает. Уточните, если необходимо удалить произвольное количество пустых списков.

Если нужно удалить из словаря весь ключ, где находится пустой список, со всеми значениями:

```
flag = False
for i in d:
    for j in d[i]:
        if len(j) == 0:
            del d[i]
            flag = True
            break
    if flag:
        break
```